# Is it possible to initialize array in an interface?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, interface, initialization

Is it possible to initialize an array in an interface using a `for` instruction?

Comment: Using a `for` instruction makes a big difference to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Simple question - Is it posible to initalize array in an interface?

Yes.

> This works but i want to initialize array by "for" intsruction. Ok thanks for help

That's not a simple question ;)

You can't do this strictly because you can't add a static block to an interface. But you can have a nested `class` or `enum`.

IMHO, that could be more confusing than useful as follows:

```
public interface I {
    int[] values = Init.getValue();

    enum Init {;
        static int[] getValue() {
            int[] arr = new int[5];
            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
                arr[i] = i * i;
            return arr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MikeMyers If the question looks too simple, it can mean there is a deeper question the OP hasn't realised they need to ask. ;)

Comment: Yes this is too complicated. The only reason for I wanted to create an interface is becasue i wanted to easly refer to the fields from other class. These fields can be static so i think that the better and simpler solution is make class with static { }. One more time thanks for help.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just try it out?

```
public interface Example {
    int[] values = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11 };
}
```

Comment: This works but i want to initialize array by "for" intsruction. Ok thanks for help

Comment: @user1555754...Then first try on your own that thing (initializing an array using for loop).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but only if it's static. In fact, any variables declared in an interface will automatically be static.

```
public interface ITest {
    public static String[] test = {"1", "2"}; // this is ok
    public String[] test2 = {"1", "2"}; // also ok, but will be silently converted to static by the compiler
}
```

You can't have static initializers though.

```
public interface ITest {
    public static String[] test;
    static {
        // this is not OK. No static initializers allowed in interfaces.
    }
}
```

Obviously, you can't have constructors in interfaces.

Comment: I don't think it is a good practice to do this in an interface. Interface is used to describe behaviour, not state.

Comment: @TomislavNovoselec One could argue that it's a constant, not a state variable (although an enum would be more appropriate for that). But sure, in general I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. See the code:

```
public interface Test {
  int[] a= {1,2,3};
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i1 = Test.a[0];
    System.out.println(i1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I agreed with existing answers.

Further, I don’t think it’s a good idea to define data in an interface.
See "Effective Java":

> Item 19: Use interfaces only to define types
>
> The constant interface pattern is a poor use of interface.

To export constants in interface is bad idea.